# Reading dataframe and converting to text file

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with some datasets that I imported from csv into dataframe using pandas. Problem is I think there is one column that looks like dictonary.
"JUPYTER INLINE OUTPUT" :

```
region_shape_attributes
0   {"name":"point","cx":1,"cy":2}
1   {"name":"point","cx":11,"cy":22}
2   {"name":"point","cx":111,"cy":222}
3   {"name":"point","cx":1111,"cy":2222}
```

How can I traverse through above dataframe and get cx and cy value to be stored in text file.
" Text file"

```
1 11 111 1111
2 22 222 2222
```

Any help really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You'd better fix the way you loaded the dataframe. It really look like you load a file with a wrong format...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that does that. Please note that the first line is only needed if `region_shape_attributes` is read as a string. If it's already a dictionary, it's not needed.

```
df["region_shape_attributes"] = df.region_shape_attributes.apply(json.loads)

pd.json_normalize(df.region_shape_attributes)[["cx", "cy"]].transpose()
```

The result is:

```
    0   1    2     3
cx  1  11  111  1111
cy  2  22  222  2222
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?